# Evenly distribute data to multiple cpu with MPI GatherV

Tags: mpi

I am trying to implement load redistribution in my MPI program.

Specifically, I need to evenly distribute data that is spread across multiple CPUs back to a few CPUs (since only those CPUs have the information needed for the calculation).

A simple schematic would look like this
: [Ideal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXAhg.jpg)

I haven't found an MPI function that does this directly yet, so I'm using MPI_GatherV to gather the data onto a single CPU and then MPI_ScatterV to distribute the work to the desired CPUs, as shown :
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOT71.jpg)

This way, I can calculate with this distributed data and then reverse MPI_GatherV and MPI_ScatterV to re-balance the load correctly, but I wonder if there is a more ideal way.

Comment: What about `MPI_Alltoallv()` ?

Comment: Thanks @GillesGouaillardet. I modified my code with ALLTOALLV and it works very well. I misunderstood ALLTOALLV as a function that can only be used when all CPUs are involved.

Comment: Well, since `MPI_Alltoallv()` is a collective operation, it must be invoked by all the ranks of the communicator. That being said, it is possible to send/recv zero size messages.